# Proving the impossibility of filling polygons of $n$ sides with the area contained by $n-1$ dots within it

Tags: area, polygons

Pretty self explanatory.

If I have a quadrilateral, I'm pretty sure I can't place 3 dots randomly on the quadrilateral in any position and claim that the area contained by these dots is equal to the area of the quadrilateral. I think this applies to polygons with more sides too.

[image]

I may be wrong, but if this is true, does this concept have a name? If not, does it need to be proven- how would I do that?

Edit: I forgot to mention, but as pointed out this does not apply to convex polygons- can it be proven for concave polygons?

Comment: This is not true if the polygon is not convex.

Comment: Ahh my bad, regarding only concave polygons

Comment: You want to look up "minimum bounding box of a convex hull"